# Update a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a jQuery script for refresh the content of a div. The content is get from an external page like mypage.php. The code is this:

page.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//var first_load =
function firstLoad()
{
 $('#load_tweets').load('mypage.php');//.fadeIn("slow");
}
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('mypage.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="firstLoad()";>        
<div id="load_tweets"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If i get the content from mypage.php, that is a php script with an echo command at the end, all work fine. But now i need to get the content of div from here:

```
http://37.187.90.121:3874/currentsong?sid=1&c=
```

The output of this source is like this:

> ```
> Inna - Un Momento
> ```

If i  replace  `"myage.php"` with `"37.187.90.121:3874/currentsong?sid=1&c="` the jquery script in `page.htm` don't work and return a **blank** output. What is the problem?

**EDIT1:** 
ok is a policy problem, how i can resolve it?

**EDIT2:**+
The proxy php page solution don't work. 
I have make this php page:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("http://37.187.90.121:3874/currentsong");
?>
```

But i have this error message:

```
Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/mhd-01/www.radiowhitecrash.com/htdocs/Player/GTitle/current_g2.php on line 2

Warning: file_get_contents(http://37.187.90.121:3874/currentsong) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/mhd-01/www.radiowhitecrash.com/htdocs/Player/GTitle/current_g2.php on line 2
```

**Edit3:**
The external service give me a javascript to get the information:

```
window.centovacast===undefined&&(window.centovacast={}),window.centovacast.options===undefined&&(window.centovacast.options={}),window.centovacast.loader===undefined&&(window.centovacast.loader={attempts:0,external_jquery:!1,loaded:!1,ready:!1,widget_definitions:{},url:"",load_script:function(e){var t=document.createElement("script");t!==undefined&&(t.setAttribute("type","text/javascript"),t.setAttribute("src",e),t!==undefined&&document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t))},load_widget:function(e){var t=this.widget_definitions[e];t.ref===null&&(t.ref=t.define(jQuery))},jq_get_jsonp:function(e,t,n){return jQuery.ajax({type:"GET",url:e,data:t,success:n,dataType:"jsonp"})},jq_ready:function(){this.ready=!0;for(var e in this.widget_definitions)typeof this.widget_definitions[e].init=="function"&&this.widget_definitions[e].init(jQuery)},jq_loaded:function(){this.external_jquery||jQuery.noConflict(),jQuery.getJSONP=this.jq_get_jsonp;for(var e in this.widget_definitions)this.load_widget(e);this.loaded=!0;var t=this;jQuery(document).ready(function(){t.jq_ready()})},wait:function(){setTimeout(function(){window.centovacast.loader.check()},100)},check:function(){typeof jQuery=="undefined"?(this.wait(),this.attempts++):this.jq_loaded()},init:function(){var e=document.getElementsByTagName("script"),t=e[e.length-1],n;n=t.getAttribute.length!==undefined?t.getAttribute("src"):t.getAttribute("src",2),n.match(/^https?:\/\//i)||(n=window.location.href),this.url=n.replace(/(\.(?:[a-z]{2,}|[0-9]+)(:[0-9]+)?\/).*$/i,"$1"),this.external_jquery=typeof jQuery!="undefined",this.external_jquery||this.load_script(this.url+"system/jquery.min.js"),this.check()},add:function(e,t,n){this.widget_definitions[e]||(this.widget_definitions[e]={define:n,init:t,ref:null}),this.loaded&&this.load_widget(e),this.ready&&t(jQuery)}},window.centovacast.loader.init()),window.centovacast.loader.add("streaminfo",function(e){e.extend(window.centovacast.streaminfo.settings,window.centovacast.options.streaminfo),window.centovacast.streaminfo.settings.manual||window.centovacast.streaminfo.run()},function(e){return window.centovacast.options.streaminfo=e.extend({},window.centovacast.options.streaminfo,window.centovacast.streaminfo?window.centovacast.streaminfo.config:null),window.centovacast.streaminfo={pollcount:0,settings:{poll_limit:60,poll_frequency:6e4},state:{},registry:{},check_username:function(e){e+="";if(!this.registry[e]){if(this.registry.length==1){for(var t in this.registry)e=t;return e}return""}return e},get_streaminfo_element:function(t,n){return e("#"+this.registry[t].id[n])},_handle_json:function(t){if(!t)return;var n=this.check_username(t.rid);!n.length&&t.requestdata&&(n=this.check_username(t.requestdata.rid));if(!n.length)return;if(t.type=="error"){var r=t?t.error:"No JSON object";this.get_streaminfo_element(n,"song").html('<span title="'+r+'">Unavailable</span>'),typeof this.settings.on_error_callback=="function"&&this.settings.on_error_callback(r)}else{var i,s=t.data[0];this.state=s,t.data[0].songchanged=s.song!=this.settings.lastsong,typeof this.settings.before_change_callback=="function"&&this.settings.before_change_callback(t);for(i in s)i!="song"&&(typeof s[i]=="string"||typeof s[i]=="number")&&this.get_streaminfo_element(n,i).html(s[i]);if(typeof s.track=="object"){for(i in s.track)i!="buyurl"&&i!="imageurl"&&i!="playlist"&&(typeof s.track[i]=="string"||typeof s.track[i]=="number")&&this.get_streaminfo_element(n,"track"+i).html(s.track[i]);this.get_streaminfo_element(n,"playlist").html(typeof s.track.playlist=="object"?s.track.playlist.title:"");var o=s.track.buyurl?s.track.buyurl:"javascript:void(0)";e("img#"+this.registry[n].id.trackimageurl).attr("src",s.track.imageurl),e("a#"+this.registry[n].id.trackbuyurl).attr("href",o)}typeof this.settings.after_change_callback=="function"&&this.settings.after_change_callback(t);var u=s.song;u&&u!=this.registry[n].current_song&&(this.get_streaminfo_element(n,"song").fadeOut("fast",function(){e(this).html(u),e(this).fadeIn("fast")}),this.registry[n].current_song=u)}},handle_json:function(e,t,n){e&&window.centovacast.streaminfo._handle_json(e)},poll:function(t){var n=(this.settings.local?"/":window.centovacast.loader.url)+"external/rpc.php",r={m:"streaminfo.get",username:t,charset:this.registry[t].charset,mountpoint:this.registry[t].mountpoint,rid:t};e.getJSONP(n,r,this.handle_json)},_poll_all:function(){for(var e in this.registry)typeof e=="string"&&this.poll(e);(this.settings.poll_limit===0||this.pollcount++<this.settings.poll_limit)&&setTimeout(this.poll_all,this.settings.poll_frequency)},poll_all:function(){window.centovacast.streaminfo._poll_all()},register:function(e,t,n,r){this.registry[t]||(this.registry[t]={charset:n,mountpoint:r,current_song:"",id:{}});var i=e.match(/^cc_strinfo_([a-z]+)_/);i&&(this.registry[t].id[i[1]]=e)},load:function(){var t=e(this).attr("id");if(typeof t!="string")return;var n=t.replace(/^cc_strinfo_[a-z]+_/,""),r="",i="",s=/_cs-([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$/,o=s.exec(n);o&&(r=o[1],n=n.replace(s,"")),s=/_mp-([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$/,o=s.exec(n),o&&(i=o[1],n=n.replace(s,"")),window.centovacast.streaminfo.register(t,n,r,i)},run:function(){e(".cc_streaminfo").each(window.centovacast.streaminfo.load),window.centovacast.streaminfo.poll_all()}}});
```

You can check it at this link:
http://cp.eu2.fastcast4u.com:2199/system/streaminfo.js

Unfortunaly with no identation and in add i have few experiences with javascript i cant' edit the output of this script.

This script give me an output like:

> "Radio Name - Author - Title of song"

and this is a link (if you click on it open another page).

I need to get only "Author - Title of song" with no link. Any idea?

**Edit4:**

I have make another test, i have call the streaminfo.js in a span and i prove to use the document.getX of javascript to get the content of the span in various ways, but i get "undefined" output:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://cp.eu2.fastcast4u.com:2199/system/streaminfo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('cc_streaminfo')[0];
document.write("w1" + document.getElementsByClassName('cc_streaminfo')[0]);
document.write("w2" + document.getElementsByClassName('cc_streaminfo')[1]);
document.write("w3" +  document.getElementsByClassName('cc_streaminfo')[2]);
var container = document.getElementById ("cc_strinfo_summary_radiowhite");
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");
 document.write("il mio  script: " + spans[0] + "!");
document.write("il mio  script: " + container + "!");
//var first_load = 
function firstLoad()
{
 $('#load_tweets').load('current_g.php?song=ciao');//.fadeIn("slow");
}
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('current_g.php?song=' + cc_streaminfo).fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="firstLoad()";>   
<br>  
<span id="cc_strinfo_summary_radiowhite" class="cc_streaminfo">sss</span>
<div id="load_tweets"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This problem is due to [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). A possible solution would be to use `mypage.php` as a proxy which fetches the content from the remote page. Your jQuery code would then be able to access it just fine.

Comment: ok it's a policy problem, how i need to write in mypage.php for make the proxy?

Comment: Simply use `file_get_contents()` or cURL to get the contents of the remote page and echo it in `mypage.php`. If you're confused about these functions, search for examples on Google. You'll find plenty of them. The PHP manual documentation is great, too.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has something to do with CORS. Basically, unless the webpage at 37.187.90.121 explicitly states that it trusts the sources of the domain under which your website is running, your browser will not make the request.

If you are the owner of 37.187.90.121, you can add custom headers to allow inclusion of your response in other webpages.

Check your javascript console of your browser to get more details.

Comment: I'm not the owner of 37.187.90.121, is part of a paid service but i can't edit it, i can only use the output.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery to get (*`.load()`*) the contents from a div on another page ( same domain ) to add to a div on the current page is like :

```
$("#dividoncurrentpage").load("/otherpage.php #dividonotherpage");
```

Is this what you need ?

Comment: It seems the OP is trying to fetch the contents from a **remote** page, which wouldn't work because of the Same-Origin Policy, AFAIK.

Comment: sure ( it wasn't clear ) to me anyways ..

Answer (score 0):

It's because:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

mstaessen has explained on the post above.

The alternative solution is: You can create a file called, for example song.php and add the following code.

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("http://37.187.90.121:3874/currentsong?sid=1&c=");
?>
```

And update the script to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//var first_load =
function firstLoad()
{
 $('#load_tweets').load('song.php');//.fadeIn("slow");
}
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('song.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use jQuery $.ajax to get the content. [Link](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

By using $.ajax you have many ways to work around this issue like crossDomain or get the result in Json format by setting the dataType  that you will receive from the server to JSON or JSONP